# How does the FlightAware app get this keyboard on IOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I would like to have this same keyboard on my IOS app that has both letters and numbers. What package is this?

[image: Keyboard with numbers and letters]

I have tried to use

```
TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword
)
```

But it only works on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the FlightAware example, the digits above the keyboard are not actually part of the keyboard, but rather are a custom [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618596-inputaccessoryview/). (This is evidenced by some weird chrome during autocomplete; [the color being a bit off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bh9Q.png) in dark/contrast mode; the [screen snapshot captured by springboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRZbn.jpg) hides the alpha keys, but not the digits; etc.)

Theoretically, you could do this yourself, e.g.:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.inputAccessoryView = createAccessoryView()
        textField.returnKeyType = .search
        textField.textContentType = .flightNumber
        textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func didTapDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let text = sender.titleLabel?.text else { return }
        textField.insertText(text)
    }

    func createAccessoryView() -> UIView {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 55)
        let accessoryView = UIInputView(frame: rect)

        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: accessoryView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5))
        stackView.spacing = 6
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        accessoryView.addSubview(stackView)

        let buttonTitles = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

        for title in buttonTitles {
            let button = KeyboardStyleButton()
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDigit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        return accessoryView
    }
}

class KeyboardStyleButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4039216638, green: 0.4039216042, blue: 0.4039215446, alpha: 1)
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

---

I created this example to mimic the appearance of dark mode on my iPhone 15 Pro Max simulator, but it is incomplete (e.g., the long-press behavior, different colors, sizes, and fonts for different devices, iOS versions, display mode (light, dark, high-contrast, etc.), accessibility settings, device rotations, etc.). I do not believe that iOS programmatically exposes the keyboard appearance details, so there is quite a bit of work to get all of these permutations correct.

Given the amount of work that entails, you might want to research third-party libraries that have done all of this for you. I have not used any and, therefore, have no recommendations to make. Besides, recommendations for third-party libraries are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, anyway.